# How to cope with negative prediction value in a linear regression implementation in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, linear-regression

I implemented code in PHP for linear regression, the idea was to take delivery date for each customer (however many delivery dates per customer there were in the DB) and then to use these delivery dates (converted to days) as a linear regression equation as the y parameter, to eventually prediction a future delivery date/order date, and based on this prediction and comparison to the current date, the system would take some action like send push notification reminders. My code for the implementation is as follows:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db, $conn) or die(mysql_error());



    //Outer Loop to save all eligable customer ID's

    $idarray=array();

$firstloop=mysql_query("Select id FROM ordering GROUP BY id",$conn);
$number_of_rows_initial=mysql_num_rows($firstloop);
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($firstloop, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false){
  $idarray[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
 // print_r($idarray);
}


for($counter=0; $counter<$number_of_rows_initial; $counter++)   
        {
            $id=$idarray[$counter]['id'];



//First confirm if user is already registered via website

$result = mysql_query("SELECT TO_DAYS(date) FROM ordering WHERE id=$id",$conn);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
// mysql_query($result,$conn) or die(mysql_error();

//echo $num_rows;


$data = array();
$days=array();
$xAxis=array();

$ldate=array();

while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false){
  $data[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
}

// print_r($data); // print result


//This part is working now!!!!

for ($x = $num_rows-1 ; $x > 0; $x--) {
    $days[$x] = $data[$x]['TO_DAYS(date)'] -$data[$x-1]['TO_DAYS(date)'];

    $xAxis[$x]=$x;
}

$days[0]=30;
print_r("<br />",$days);
//print_r($xAxis);




//my implementation of regression calculation

 // calculate sums
  $x_sum = (array_sum($xAxis));
  $y_sum = array_sum($days);
  echo "<br />","Customer ID is: ",$id,"<br />";
  echo "Sum of X Axis: ",$x_sum, "<br />";
  echo "Sum of Y Axis: ",$y_sum,"<br />" ;

  $xx_sum = 0;
  $xy_sum = 0;

  for($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {

    $xy_sum+=($xAxis[$i]*$days[$i]);
    $xx_sum+=($xAxis[$i]*$xAxis[$i]);

  }

  // calculate slope
  $m = (($num_rows * $xy_sum) - ($x_sum * $y_sum)) / (($num_rows * $xx_sum) - ($x_sum * $x_sum));

  // calculate intercept
  $b = ($y_sum - ($m * $x_sum)) / $num_rows;

$predict=($m*($num_rows+1))+$b;

echo "The Slope of the Representative line is: ",$m,"<br />";
echo "The Y intercept is ",$b,"<br />";
echo "Predicted next date of delivery in days (from last delivery date) is: ", $predict,"<br />";


//Final Date Calculation

$lastdate=mysql_query("SELECT TO_DAYS(date) FROM ordering WHERE id=$id",$conn);
$num_rows_date = mysql_num_rows($lastdate);
while (($row_date = mysql_fetch_array($lastdate, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false){
  $ldate[] = $row_date; // add the row in to the results (data) array
}
echo "Total number of records for the given id are: ",$num_rows_date, "<br />";
$ldatefinal=$ldate[$num_rows_date-1]['TO_DAYS(date)'];

echo "Last date in the records for the given ID is ",$ldatefinal,"<br />";
echo "Last date + Prediction days = ",$ldatefinal+$predict,"<br />";


$currentdate=mysql_query("SELECT TO_DAYS(CURDATE())",$conn);

$dcrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($currentdate);

//$dhold=$dcrow['TO_DAYS(CURDATE())'];
//echo "Current Date is: ",$dcrow['TO_DAYS(CURDATE())'],"<br /" ;

//UPON EXECUTION NOTHING BELOW GETS ExEcuted ??

//echo "Last date + Predicted days = ";




if (( (($ldatefinal+$predict) - $dcrow['TO_DAYS(CURDATE())']) <3 )&& $predict>0){

echo "Time to Order<br />","</br />";
}else if((( (($ldatefinal+$predict) - $dcrow['TO_DAYS(CURDATE())']) >3 && $predict>0) )){
echo "You Got Gas!!<br />","</br />";
}else{
    echo "Linear Regression not Suitable for this Record ID","<br />";
}

}
mysql_close($conn);
```

Every thing seems to work perfect except for the times when the prediction comes up with negative numbers, I have for now chosen to ignore these by using the " echo "Linear Regression not Suitable for this Record ID","
";" but I am sure there must be a better way to accommodate this type of scenarios, I am just not sure how to in my case, especially using the date format. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I must say this forum and of course its users have been extremely kind and generous with their time and knowledge in the past for me, and hope you guys can point me in the right direction this time as well. Hamood